# How to use "OR" clause in Firebase Query

Tags: ios, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I want to query my data with a where clause with an or. Below is my current code.

```
let friendQuery = friendMapRef.queryEqualToValue(loggedUser.UserId, childKey: "sender_id")
```

And its retrieving fine, but i want to match if any friend map has sender_id value as my userid or receiver_id as my userid value. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only query on a single property. You may be able to combine the values you want to query on into a single property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: by looking at the link its clear that i can combine 2 conditions and thats an AND clause. i want to check OR. can you point me in any other post. because i tried so many stack posts but no luck.

Comment: For an `OR` you'll have to change your data structure to create a separate list of the values you're searching for and then for each of those the corresponding keys of the items that match it. If you'd like a concrete example, edit your question to include a minimal snippet of the actual JSON that you use.

Comment: i got your point. finally i have to change my data structure. thank you for clearing the doubt.

Comment: actually what i did is, i retrieved twice with both key and merged both the list and sorted by date time. this is quickest and i don't have to change my database also.

Comment: Good to hear. If you can post that as an answer (including a minimal code snippet), it might be useful to future visitors.